# Spring boot fiegn client

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feignEncoder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsConfiguration: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [feign.codec.Encoder]: Factory method 'feignEncoder' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/form/FormEncoder
```

Comment: please 1. format your question properly and 2. add any sort of information (pom content, spring boot version, application.yml) in order to help future visitors with this issue

Answer (score 0):

This happened due to incorrect dependency jars. I deleted my local .m2 folder and build the project again and it is working fine now.